# Zeppelin Spark println with RDD foreach does not shown on notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-zeppelin, println

I use Zeppelin with Spark (Scala)

```
val sparkLicTextFilePath = "/home/tt/Software/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/LICENSE"

val licLines = sc.textFile(sparkLicTextFilePath)

licLines.foreach(line=>println(line))
```

However, nothing is print in the notebook so far. I did try with `.collect()` to see if the RDD is empty or not. The RDD is ok and load file correctly.

Here is Zeppelin notebook screenshot

[image: zeppelin_println]

And some info about version of Zeppelin and spark

[image: zeppelin 0.8.0]

Zeppelin 0.8.0

[image: Spark 2.3.2]

Spark 2.3.2

Comment: `foreach` is executed by the **Excecutor**, and Zeppelin is running the **Driver** - That's why you don't see the output, because it was printed in the stdout of other process. `foreach` isn't intended for debugging, if you want to print the contents of an RDD you need to `collect` and then print the returned collection - be aware that if it is too big it will blow your memory.

Comment: to add to Luis' answer. If you want to inspect data on zeppelin, one of the easiest way is to use `.show`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print few lines of the licLines and not all.
Its probably that zeppelin is unable to print whole file.

Try:

```
val fewLicLines = licLines.take(5)
fewLicLines.foreach(line=>println(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

```
%spark
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.charset.Charset

val rdd = sc.textFile("some/file")
val rdd1 = rdd.map(s => s.split(",")).map(l => (l(2), 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
val rdd6 = rdd1.map(a=>(a._2,a._1)).sortByKey(ascending = false)

// this line shows blank
rdd6.collect().foreach(println)
// this also does not print
println("hello from scala")

//this works, but is DF not RDD
rdd6.toDF().show(200)
```

After some checks, I found that the problem was the Zeppelin version (zeppelin-0.8.1-bin-all). There is a bug which got fixed in the next version, thus I switched to version 0.8.2.

This worked for me.